# DNS Resolution Incredibly Slow

Tags: powershell, dns

I am attempting to take a list of IPs and resolve them to DNS name using Powershell. If the host cannot resolve I am trying to write it out to an error file. Currently the script runs incredibly fast (sub 10ms) on IPs that are capable of resolving to a hostname, but for ones that do not resolve the script takes an extended period of time (roughly 4500 ms per IP). I have tried timing just the DNS resolution on non-resolving IPs, and I get roughly 65 ms when they fail, so I'm not sure what is adding this extra drag time of over 4000 ms to the resolution. This is getting to be a very intensive timing process when processing more than 1,000 IPs. Script below contains measure-command statements I've been using for trouble shooting.

```
    $ips = get-content ".\source_ip.txt"
    $outFile = ".\resolvedTest.txt"
    $errorFile = ".\resolveErrorTest.txt"

    $commandTimes = @()

    foreach ($ip in $ips){
        $measure = Measure-Command{
            try {[string] $hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip).HostName}
            catch [system.exception]{$hostname = $ip}

            $hostname = $hostname.Replace("@{HostName=","")
            $hostname = $hostname.Replace("}","")

            if ($hostname -eq $ip){
                Add-Content $errorFile "$hostname, Error"
            } else {
                Add-Content $outFile "$ip, $hostname"
            }
        }

        Write-Host $measure.TotalMilliseconds
        $commandTimes += ,$measure.TotalMilliseconds
    }
```

Comment: `[System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress($ip).HostName` should be a string.  Casting [string] $hostname is unnecessary.  The two lines using `.Replace()` are unnecessary.  Removing these will help with speed, but likely this is not the issue.

This is reverse DNS, so there's no native cmdlets that I know of that would do this and hopefully include a timeout.

Also, you could remove the if structure and move the error part to the catch block in place of the part that sets $hostname and move the output part.  you'd end up with `try {};catch{};Add-content....`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove unnecessary statements :

```
$ips = "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"
$outFile = "c:\resolvedTest.txt"
$errorFile = "c:\resolveErrorTest.txt"

foreach ($ip in $ips){

    $measure = Measure-Command {
        try {
            $hostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($ip).HostName
        }
        catch {
            $hostname = $false
        }
    }

    if($hostname) {
        Write-Host ("$ip was successfully resolved to $hostname ({0:N0}ms elapsed)" -f $measure.TotalMilliseconds) -ForegroundColor Green
    } else {
        Write-Host ("$ip was not resolved ({0:N0}ms elapsed)" -f $measure.TotalMilliseconds) -ForegroundColor Red
    }

}
```

Don't know if this will be faster, though.